# Is it possible to query the latest datapoint in kairosdb for a specific tag?

Tags: kairosdb, kairos-api

I am trying to get the latest datapoint for a specific tag say `device_id` : `101` without knowing when the last datapoint might have come in. It could be 10 minutes ago or 10 days ago. How can I get the last datapoint without specifying the time range ? Is there a way to do this in KairosDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a wide time interval (say last year) and use the query property [limit](https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/restapi/QueryMetrics.html#metric-properties) and the aggregator [last](https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/restapi/Aggregators.html#last).

Comment: Would this give a query performance comparable to looking at only the last record in a year wide interval ? I hope the process wouldnt involve going through all the datapoints in the time range. I will try the query out and give my response.